# enable or disable a field in maya ui with python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I am trying to enable/disable a float field in the ui of a python script for maya, but I dont know how it is done. Here is an example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createUI(windowTitle):

    windowID = 'myWindoWID'

    if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI(windowID)

    cmds.window( windowID, title = windowTitle, sizeable = False, resizeToFitChildren = True) 

    cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns = 3, columnWidth = [(1,120), (2,120), (3,120)])

    cmds.floatField(enable = False)
    cmds.button(label = 'enable the float field', command = enableFloatField)
    cmds.button(label = 'disable the float field', command = disableFloatField)        

    cmds.showWindow()

def enableFloatField(*args):
    #enable the float field
    print 'float field enabled'


def disableFloatField(*args):
    #disable the float field
    print 'float field disabled'


createUI('my window')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your float field in a variable first.

```
my_float_field = cmds.floatField(enable = False)
```

We use functools.partial to pass this variable to your buttons' command methods.

```
cmds.button(label = 'enable the float field', command = partial(enableFloatField, my_float_field))
cmds.button(label = 'disable the float field', command = partial(disableFloatField, my_float_field))
```

In your methods, we then call `cmds.floatField()` in edit mode and edit your particular float field that you sent as a parameter.

```
def enableFloatField(float_field, *args):
    #enable the float field
    cmds.floatField(float_field, edit=True, enable=True)


def disableFloatField(float_field, *args):
    #disable the float field
    cmds.floatField(float_field, edit=True, enable=False)
```

Remember to import functools.

```
from functools import partial
```

So your whole code would be:

```
from functools import partial
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createUI(windowTitle):

    windowID = 'myWindoWID'

    if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI(windowID)

    cmds.window( windowID, title = windowTitle, sizeable = False, resizeToFitChildren = True) 

    cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns = 3, columnWidth = [(1,120), (2,120), (3,120)])

    my_float_field = cmds.floatField(enable = False)
    cmds.button(label = 'enable the float field', command = partial(enableFloatField, my_float_field))
    cmds.button(label = 'disable the float field', command = partial(disableFloatField, my_float_field))

    cmds.showWindow()

def enableFloatField(float_field, *args):
    #enable the float field
    cmds.floatField(float_field, edit=True, enable=True)


def disableFloatField(float_field, *args):
    #disable the float field
    cmds.floatField(float_field, edit=True, enable=False)


createUI('my window')
```

The important thing to note here in `cmds.floatField(float_field, edit=True, enable=False)` is the `edit=True` flag. This flag calls the UI method in `edit` mode, meaning any paramaters you pass into this UI method will be used to *edit* an existing UI element, which will be the first parameter of the method; in this case `float_field`, which contains the name of your float field which might look something like `'myWindoWID|rowColumnLayout6|floatField11'`.

Another such mode flag is `query=True`, which will let you query parameter(s) of a UI element. If both of these flags are not present, Maya will assume that the method was called in `create` mode.

Hope this helps.