# Switchable Radio Buttons (editing a command)

Tags: python, user-interface, checkbox, radio-button, maya

I'm a bit stuck on how to write the correct syntax for editing a command.

way down in my radioOn and radioOff commands, I would like the enable / disable checkbox to enable or disable the radio buttons.

```
from functools import partial
import maya.cmds as cmds

def one ():
    print '1'

def two ():
    print '2'



winID = 'xx'
if cmds.window(winID, exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI(winID)


window = cmds.window(winID, sizeable = False, title="Resolution Switcher", widthHeight=(300, 100) )

cmds.columnLayout( )
cmds.text (label = '')
cmds.text (label = '')
cmds.checkBoxGrp( cat = (1,'left', 20), ncb = 1, l1='  DISABLE', offCommand = partial(radioOn, a), onCommand = partial(radioOff, a) )
a = cmds.radioButtonGrp( cat = [(1,'left', 90),(2, 'left', 100)], numberOfRadioButtons=2,   on1 = 'one ()' , on2 = 'two ()' )
cmds.text (label = '')

def radioOff (a, *args):
    print 'radios off'
    a(ed=True, enable=False)

def radioOn (a, *args):
    print 'radios on'
    a(ed=True, enable=False)


cmds.showWindow( window )
```

I've tried to get an idea from examples such as the one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888857/enable-or-disable-a-field-in-maya-ui-with-python), but 
but when I put down `cmds.radioButtonGrp(a, ed=True, enable=False)` it just keeps creating new radio buttons, not unlike what was shown in the example with float fields.

bottom line is - I just want the radio buttons to be greyed out and disabled whenever I hit the checkbox. Speaking of which - Is it possible to grey out the radio buttons the same way float fields can? I noticed that disabling them only makes them unclickable - but not greyed out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from functools import partial
import maya.cmds as cmds

def one (*args):
    print '1'

def two (*args):
    print '2'

def radioSwitch (a, state, *args):
    if state:
        cmds.radioButtonGrp(a, e=True, enable=False)
    else:
        cmds.radioButtonGrp(a, e=True, enable=True)

winID = 'xx'
if cmds.window(winID, exists=True):
    cmds.deleteUI(winID)


window = cmds.window(winID, sizeable = False, title="Resolution Switcher", widthHeight=(300, 100) )

cmds.columnLayout( )
cmds.text (label = '')
cmds.text (label = '')
cb_disable = cmds.checkBoxGrp( cat = (1,'left', 20), ncb = 1, l1='  DISABLE', offCommand = "" , onCommand = "" )
a = cmds.radioButtonGrp( cat = [(1,'left', 90),(2, 'left', 100)], enable=True, numberOfRadioButtons=2,   on1 = one , on2 = two )
cmds.checkBoxGrp(cb_disable, e=1, offCommand = partial(radioSwitch, a, False))
cmds.checkBoxGrp(cb_disable, e=1, onCommand = partial(radioSwitch, a, True))
cmds.text (label = '')
cmds.showWindow( window )
```